# Raspberry Pi Wifi dongle

Tags: raspberry-pi2

I'm not quit sure if I'm on the right site for this, but I'll give it a try. I have a couple of usb devices plugged in my Raspberry Pi model B. But when I plug in a WiFi dongle, it just shuts down all the other usb devices, and the dongle itself doesn't even work. Has anyone any idea what moght solve my problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not. Questions like this are more suited for http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: are you using a hub?

Comment: okay, thank you @dovetalk !
and Miguel, no, I'm not. There's 1 usb device connected.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is the amount of current that your Raspberry Pi is able to source. If you are not using a Hub it makes sense that when you connect your WiFi dongle the USB ports are disable to avoid getting to much current from your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Any idea where I can fine a proper charger?

Comment: You can google for a Raspberry Pi Hub. I have found this one [PIHUB](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pihub-a-robust-powered-hub-for-your-pi/)

Answer (score 1):

`WiFi dongle` consumes lot of USB power. You need external powered USB hub, or you can maximize the input current for your `pi`

> Based on its documentation, Pi 2 can be powered up to 2A current

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. It was easy to fix for me, but this may not help. This turned out to be a settings / driver error for me. If this does not work, you should try a different power source with a 2A current.

I have an answer for this. If you can run the command 'lsusb' okay, and it shows your wifi dongle is attached, you will need to edit your /etc/network/interfaces file.

First, find your ip and gateway settings

> ifconfig

That should display your ip address. Write down the default gateway and this IP address.

Now, enter this into the command line:

> Sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

So, that has opened the interfaces file. Completely rewrite the file to the following (YOU SHOULD TAKE A PICTURE OF THE CURRENT FILE IN CASE THIS GOES WRONG):

> auto lo 
>   iface lo inet loopback 
>     
>    #auto eth0 
>    #allow-hotplug eth0
>   
>    #iface eth0 inet dhcp
>   
>   allow hotplug wlan0
>   iface wlan0 inet static
>           address you_got_this_in_step_1
>           network 192.168.0.225     #Change this to your setting.
>           gateway default_gateway_from_step_1
>           dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
>           wpa-ssid YOUR_NETWORK_SSID
>           wpa-psk YOUT_NETWORK_PASSKEY
>   
>   allow-hotpug wlan1
>   iface wlan1 inet manual
>           wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

ctrl+x and save the file, yes on overwrite

> sudo service networking restart

The pi should do some things and restart okay. If not, please set the file back to the original (should have screenshotted the file).

I also recommend that you do this locally and not through SSH.

Thanks for reading my answer and I hope it helps.